# c# write the data entered from the textboxes to the text document with a space between them

Tags: c#

write the data entered from the textboxes to the text document with a space or # between them.

i can write data to txt file from textboxes but i cant put space between them.

Comment: What you have tried yet!! show that so that the stack family could help you

Comment: "I want" isn't a question or problem statement. What have you tried? What issue are you facing specifically?

Comment: i can write to text document but i can't put any spaces between them.

Comment: Could you share the code you have tried so far ?

Comment: StreamWriter SW = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\mac\txt.txt");
            SW.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            SW.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
it write to txt document but i can't put any spaces between them

Answer (score 1):

i solved this 
`StreamWriter SW = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\mac\txt.txt");
            string hepsi = textBox1.Text +"#"+ textBox2.Text;
            SW.WriteLine(hepsi);`

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamWriter SW = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\mac\txt.txt"); 
SW.WriteLine(textBox1.Text); SW.WriteLine(textBox2.Text); 
//rather use string as below code
String textToBeWritten = ""; 
textToBeWritten += textBox1.Text;
textToBeWritten += "#"+textBox2.Text;   //how many textBoxes like that you want
//finally write using
SW.WriteLine(textToBeWritten );
```

Comment: its not working even if it works useless for me because max 20 rows 9 columns data can be entered.

Comment: use StringBuilder class instead

Answer (score 0):

You can create a collection of all the text, then use String.Join with the separator, in your case a space, and then write to file. Moreover in the example you have shown, method WriteLine would be writing text on separate lines in the file.

```
    var textToWrite = string.Join(" ", new[] { "text1", "text2" });

    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\mac\txt.txt"))
    {
        writer.Write(textToWrite);
    }
```